# How to turn on disabled messages in drcsim nightly temporarily?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

such as:

```
/atlas/debug/l_foot_contact
/atlas/debug/r_foot_contact
```

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2690/how-to-turn-on-disabled-messages-in-drcsim-nightly-temporarily?/) by [sfeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/277/sfeng/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The topics you mention are part of the development aids.  Starting in the forthcoming drcsim 2.6.0 (and in the current nightly builds), they are disabled by default.  To enable them, set the environment variable `VRC_CHEATS_ENABLED` to `1`, as described in the [User Guide](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/DRC/UserGuide#Environment_variables).

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0